# Flutter permission_handler - Requesting bluetooth permissions on Android 11 & earlier

Tags: flutter

I understand bluetooth permissions were changed in Android 12, now there is a permission for scanning, and another for connecting.

Using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

What should I be doing for Android 11 & earlier for bluetooth to work in my app?

```
void RequestPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus locationPermission = await Permission.location.request();
    PermissionStatus blePermission = await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    PermissionStatus bleScan = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
    PermissionStatus bleConnect = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();
  }
```

I added Permission.bluetooth.request() thinking that would work for Android versions earlier than 12, but it did not resolve it.